# Redirect not working as I'm expecting in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Environment:

```
Rails: 3.2.12
Ruby: ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16 revision 34643) [x86_64-linux]
```

In my routes.rb, I have:

```
match '/attendance', to: "attendance#attendance_dashboard"
match '/check_in', to: "attendance#check_in"
```

In my attendance_controller.rb, I have:

```
def attendance_dashboard
    @registered_and_not_checked_in = get_registered_and_not_checked_in()
end

def check_in
    logger.info("Email: #{params["party"]["email"]}")
    redirect_to attendance_url
end
```

When I do to myapp/attendance, it behaves like it should and displays a table with the last field in every row being a link to the attendance controller's check_in action and the params include the hash Party.

When I click on the link, I 404. Specifically, here's what the test.log says (the logger info is to make sure I am not bombing up until the redirect):

```
Processing by AttendanceController#check_in as HTML
  Parameters: {"party"=>{"email"=>"rrrrr.rrr@gmail.com", "event_id"=>"3", "first"=>"Rrr", "last"=>"Rrrrr", "payment"=>"0.0", "transaction_id"=>""}}
  [1m[35mBlogPost Load (0.4ms)[0m  SELECT `blog_posts`.* FROM `blog_posts` 
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.4ms)[0m  [1mSELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1[0m
Email: rrrrr.rrr@gmail.com
Completed 404 Not Found in 5ms
```

I also tried the following redirect syntax:

```
    redirect_to attendance_path
```

What am I missing?

## Routes:

This is the output of rake route:

```
         /attendance(.:format)  attendance#attendance_dashboard
check_in        /check_in(.:format) attendance#check_in
```

Note that unlike check_in, there is no "path" even though the syntax in routes.rb is the same

Comment: What's the output of `rake routes`? Does attendance show up as a route?

Comment: See my edit. I don't understand why there's a difference between attendance and check_in the way the routes were generated. Note that per my initial question, I can do my_app/attendance and it takes me to the correct place

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have this in your routes file:

```
match '/attendance', to: "attendance#attendance_dashboard", :as => :attendance
match '/check_in', to: "attendance#check_in", :as => :check_in
```

Comment: This worked. I still don't understand why the route worked for check_in but not for attendance